# Using ASP.NET SqlMembershipProvider with GUID UserID in MVC4 web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an existing ASP.NET Web Forms site I'm in the process of upgrading to an ASP.NET MVC4 Web Application.

It looks like it should be possible to use my existing membership database with the `SimpleMembershipProvider` that MVC4 web apps use by default.

The problem is that the SimpleMembershipProvider expects the `UserId` column to be of type `int`, while my existing database uses a `guid`.

Here's the relevant portion of my `web.config`:

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <remove name="SqlMembershipProvider"/>
    <add
      name="SqlMembershipProvider"
      connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
      enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
      enablePasswordReset="true"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
      requiresUniqueEmail="false"
      passwordFormat="Hashed"
      applicationName="/"
      maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="10"
      minRequiredPasswordLength="1"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
      passwordAttemptWindow="10"
      passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
      type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Attempting to change the password, for example, I get a `RuntimeBinderException`:

> "Cannot convert type 'System.Guid' to 'int'".

#### *My primary question is:* Ideally, I'd like to keep my existing database intact, and configure the MVC web app to work with it. How can I configure my MVC4 web app to use my existing database (with `GUID` `UserId`'s) as the membership database?

As a secondary question: I suppose I could change the `UserId` column to `int`; does anybody foresee any problems with that, or know the best way to go about that?

---

*This was the best lead I could find on using a `UserId` of type `GUID`: http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41201-asp-net-mvc/suggestions/3573751-use-generic-types-for-userid-in-simple-membership-*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround:

- Changed the provider type back to `System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider`
- Modify the `AccountController` to perform the actions using the `Membership` and `FormsAuthentication` classes instead of the `WebSecurity` class
- Removed the `SimpleMembershipProvider` attribute from the `AccountController`

For example, to validate a login and set a cookie:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid && Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password)) 
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName,false);
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: Aaron, can you give me more of an example how to changed your Account Controller to use the older SqlMembership provider? The majority of my apps are using forms authentication with the older aspnetdb database for authentication and authorization. I have a class that my apps  use to call into a web service to get the user's login name and then I set an authentication cookie using FormsAuthenticaiton.SetAuthCookie. I use that user to create a GenericPrincipal to set the HttpContext user to.

Comment: Essentially in web.config I set the `type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"`. See this documentation for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi Aaron, I'm finally getting back around to this and I'm wondering if you can, somehow, give me an example or share you Account Controller with me so I can get a feel for how I can modify it to use the SqlMembershipProvider and the older aspnetdb database